# While zip multiple images the images size and quality gets reduced , how to solve that?

Tags: android, image, zip, compression

I have used below function to zip multiple images from my folder, mainViewModel.getImagesList() will return array of images path which i want to added in zip folder

```
public void compressImagesToZip() throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream origin = null;
    String opd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getApplication().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.imageFolder) + "/GroTrack.zip";
    Log.e("====>>", opd);
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(opd)));
    try {
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];
        for (int i = 0; i < mainViewModel.getImagesList().size(); i++) {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(mainViewModel.getImagesList().get(i));
            origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, 2048);
            try {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(mainViewModel.getImagesList().get(i).substring(mainViewModel.getImagesList().get(i).lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;
                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, 2048)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } finally {
                origin.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Please refere this images, before zip and after zip image sizes were different

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQeWj.jpg)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBMEF.jpg)

Comment: Hard to believe. Just zip one image file and tell us size of original image file and size of unzipped image file.

Comment: Hello @blackapps i have attached images in question can you please refere those, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Impossible that imagesizes would change at zipping and unzipping and that it would still be a valid image. Show also your unzip code in another code block. where and how did you unzip all?

Comment: Hello @blackapps i have not written any code for unzip, i have used file manager and unzip the images,